# Importing Parity/OpenEthereum private keys to Geth: got zero balance

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, migration, openethereum

I have to migrate to Geth from Parity/OpenEthereum as the latter completely stopped syncing for me.

First of all I tried to copy one of my private keys exported with `parity_exportAccount()` - which appears to have a format pretty similar to Geth into Geth keystore:

```
$ cp myaccount.json ~/.ethereum/keystore/UTC--2020-09-11T05-44-30.451420645Z--0x1234561234561234561234561234561234561234
```

Now I see my account in Geth JS console - and I even can unlock it with `web3.personal.unlockAccount()`. But whenever I'm trying to call `web3.eth.getBalance()`, it always returns `0` - as well as `web3.eth.getTransactionCount()`.

Of course, I have already ensured that my account has non-zero balance on etherchain.org. I'm also sure that my Geth instance is in sync.

What should I do in order to make Geth recognizing my imported wallet's balance? Do I have to run something similar to Bitcoin-Core's `-reindex` option, or I'm doing something completely wrong? In the latter case, which procedure should I follow to correctly migrate?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I have found this to be working after starting geth in lite mode:

```
$ geth --syncmode "light"
```

The balance is getting recognized now and I can use the funds without any problems.